# Initialising plugin on replaced element in dynamic directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to initialise Swipe.js on an element in a directive. I had this working before, but I'm modifying my directive to dynamically load a template based on carousel type, then compile it, then initialise the plugin. This is my directive:

```
directive('carousel', ['$compile', '$http', '$templateCache', function($compile, $http, $templateCache) {
    var templateMap = { 
        default:    'default.html',
        products:   'partials/carousel/products.html'
    }, loader;

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            type: '@',
            slides: '=' 
        },  

        compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
            var template = templateMap[tAttrs.type];
            loader = $http.get(template, {cache: false}).success(function(html) {
                tElement.html(html);
            }); 

            return function(scope, element, attrs) {
                loader.then(function() {
                    scope.$watch('slides', function(slides) {
                        if(slides) {
                            console.log(element);
                            template = angular.element($compile(tElement.html())(scope));
                            element.replaceWith(template);
                            console.log(element);
                        }   
                    }); 
                }); 
            };  
        }   
    }   
}])
```

When I `console.log(element)` it logs the `<carousel></carousel>` element as I'd expect. When I do the `replaceWith()`, then `console.log(element)`, I'm expecting it to show the new replaced element that was loaded in, but it still logs the carousel element.

If it was replacing as I'm expecting it to, I'd do `Swipe(element)` on the new element, but obviously that won't work.

Any tips?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to maintain a jQuery reference using replaceWith](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672010/how-to-maintain-a-jquery-reference-using-replacewith)

Answer (score 0):

[`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) will return a reference to the *old* element, which is why your second `console.log()` is still printing the `<carousel>`. The documentation states that:

> The `.replaceWith()` method, like most jQuery methods, returns the
>   jQuery object so that other methods can be chained onto it. However,
>   it must be noted that **the *original* jQuery object is returned**. This
>   object refers to the element that has been removed from the DOM, not
>   the new element that has replaced it.

The way around this is to use [`.replaceAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceAll/) which does largely the same thing, but with reversed order. `.replaceAll()` returns a reference to the *new* DOM element, which should solve your problem.

Try this in your loader callback:

```
if(slides) {
    console.log(element);
    template = angular.element($compile(tElement.html())(scope));
    element.after(template);

    console.log(element);

    new Swipe(element[0], { /* ... */ });
}
```

---

Another method you could try (due to jqLite not having `.replaceAll()` is to use `.after()` and `.remove()`:

```
if(slides) {
    console.log(element);
    template = angular.element($compile(tElement.html())(scope));

    var oldElement = element;
    element = element.after(template);
    oldElement.remove();

    console.log(element);

    new Swipe(element[0], { /* ... */ });
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately won't work - `replaceAll()` isn't included in jQLite.